# Tag HTML em Helper Razor

Tags: html, razor, html-tags

Possuo código em HTML:

```
<label class="labelinput">Nº Compra<em>*</em></label>
```

Passando para o Helper ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
@Html.Label("Nº Compra:", new {@class = "labelinput"})
```

Porém não consegui adicionar a tag `<em>` com o Helper.

Como eu adiciono a tag `<em>` para ficar junto dá string do Helper?

Comment: [Ninguém melhor pra ajudar nisso que o Darin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5707259/1267304).

Answer (score 0):

Cara, é só você fazer assim:

```html
<em>
  @Html.Label("Nº Compra:", new {@class = "labelinput"})
</em>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Segundo esta resposta do Darin Dmitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5707259/1314276), implemente a seguinte extensão (modifiquei para refletir seu cenário):

```cs
namespace MeuProjeto.Extensions
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString Label(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, String ex, Func<object, HelperResult> template, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            var label = new TagBuilder("label");
            label.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
            label.InnerHtml = string.Format(
                "{0} {1}", 
                ex,
                template(null).ToHtmlString()
            );
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(label.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Uso:

```cs
@Html.Label("Nº Compra",
    @"<em>*</em>",
    new { @class = "labelinput" }
)
```

Uma dica: registre o *namespace* das suas extensões no `web.config` que está dentro do diretório `Views`:

```cs
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        ...
        <add namespace="MeuProjeto.Extensions" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```